# Using partialPlot after fitting a Random Forest model in caret

Tags: random-forest, r-caret

After I fit a randomForest using the train() function, I'm having problems invoking partialPlot() and plotmo(). Here's some reproducible code:

```
library(AER)
library(caret)

data(Mortgage)

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv"
                           ,number = 5
                           ,repeats = 10
                           ,allowParallel = TRUE)

library(doMC)

registerDoMC(cores=10)

Final.rfModel <- train(form=networth ~ ., data=Mortgage, method = "rf", metric='RMSE', trControl = fitControl, tuneLength=10, importance = TRUE)

#### partial plots fail
partialPlot(Final.rfModel$finalModel, Mortgage, "liquid")

library(plotmo)
plotmo(Final.rfModel$finalModel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some inconsistency between how some functions (including `randomForest` and `train`) handle dummy variables. Most functions in R that use the formula method will convert factor predictors to dummy variables because their models require numerical representations of the data. The exceptions to this are tree- and rule-based models (that can split on categorical predictors), naive Bayes, and a few others.

So `randomForest` will *not* create dummy variables when you use `randomForest(y ~ ., data = dat)` but `train` (and most others) will using a call like `train(y ~ ., data = dat)`.

The error occurs because `rate`, `married` and a few other predictors are factors. The dummy variables created by `train` don't have the same names so `partialPlot` can't find them.

Using the non-formula method with `train` will pass the factor predictors to `randomForest` and everything will work.

TL;DR

Use the non-formula method with `train` in this case:

```
Final.rfModel <- train(form=networth ~ ., data=Mortgage, 
                       method = "rf", 
                       metric='RMSE', 
                       trControl = fitControl, 
                       tuneLength=10, 
                       importance = TRUE)
```

Max

Comment: could you show an example of the non-formula method in train? your example still has a formula.

Comment: Hi @williamchiu. You are correct, it appears Max put the formula based method by accident. As I am sure you have already figured out, the non-formula (or default) method is to simply declare x and y thusly             S3 method for class 'default':
      train((x, y, 
      method = "rf",  
      preProcess = NULL,
      ...,